# Order by last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, default-scope

I am trying to set the default scope for my User model. Each user has one name column. The problem is that I would like to order users by the first letter of their last name. This would be the start of the last word from the name. For example, a users name may be "Kevin John Smith", I would like to order by Smith. I currently have `default_scope order('name ASC')`, but this sorts by the first letter of the first name. How would I convert this to sort by the first letter of the last name? Thanks!

Comment: If your `users` table contains a column called `lastname`,then you can do like this `default_scope order('lastname ASC')`.

Comment: @Pavan No it doesn't. Read the question.

Comment: @MarekLipka Ohh I see, first letter of the lastname.You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.select("users.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(users.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname").limit(10).order('lastname ASC')
```

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) is one of the mySQL string functions.

For PostgreSQL [`split_part`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) should work:

```
User.select("users.*, split_part(users.name, ' ', 3) AS lastname").limit(10).order('lastname ASC')
```

I am not sure, though try with `-1` too:

```
User.select("users.*, split_part(users.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname").limit(10).order('lastname ASC')
```

Because, the latter one will ensure that the last string after split is used which will cover the cases where user has just first name and last name.

Make sure you use [`unscoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class), which returns a scope for this class without taking into account the [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class).

Comment: How can I convert this to use as my `default_scope`?

Comment: try: `User.unscoped.select("users.*, split_part(users.name, ' ', -1) AS lastname")...`

Comment: But I assume that I would have to call this every time I retrieved a user as supposed to with `default_scope`, the users will always be returned in alphabetical order. I wasn't saying that I need a way to use this in harmony with the default_scope, but set this as my default_scope.

Comment: Well you'll have to, `default_scope` shouldn't be used at all if you have to order by lastname all the time in your application. Sometimes [`default_scope` is an evil](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil). IMO you should change the table schema to have separate columns for first and last names, that's the only way I see your default_scope will make any sense here.